# SD.LLBLGen.Pro.DQE dll missing. From where can i get it?

Tags: dll, llblgenpro

I have a project which uses "SD.LLBLGen.Pro.DQE.OracleMS.NET20" reference.

I did some blunder and it's missing now.

I am getting Build Error:-

> The type or namespace name 'Oracle' does not exist in the namespace
>   'SD.LLBLGen.Pro.DQE' (are you missing an assembly reference?).

Can any body help me in this, tried googling but no fruitful result??

Apologies, if the question is put in wrong section .

Answer (score 2):

If you have LLBLGen installed locally, you should find the file in a location something like this:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Solutions Design\LLBLGen Pro v3.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\Net2.0\SD.LLBLGen.Pro.DQE.OracleMS.NET20.dll`

You can correct the path of the broken reference to point to this file. Or, better yet, copy this file into your source control location for the project so other team members can compile the project without having the full LLBLGen installation.

If you don't have this file locally but have a customer ID you can log in here to download the installer:
https://www.llblgen.com/pages/customerlogin.aspx

I suspect the [trial version](https://www.llblgen.com/pages/trial.aspx) also comes with this file, but have not tried that approach.